# Python Looping through only Last List Value

Tags: python, gspread

I am using a package to query a list of cells in my Google Sheet and and I'm looking to pass the elements in a different list (forecast) to the values of the Google Sheet list. However, When I run my loops it is passing the last element in my forecast list through each Google Sheet cell in my list. Am I setting up my for loops incorrectly? Is it because of the list element types?

I tried to follow the "Updating Cells" (in batch) section of the library: [Gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)

Here is what the two lists look like:

**forecasting_range:**

Type = `<class 'gspread.models.Cell'>`

```
[<Cell R2C3 '179'>, <Cell R3C3 ''>,...,<Cell R32C3 ''>]
```

**forecasted_session_column:**

Type = `<class 'list'>`

```
 ['179', '754.6296810633474', '638.2052995605169',...,'607.1381980696942']
```

**Here is my Loop setup:**

```
for cell in forecasting_range:
    for forecast in forecasted_session_column:
        cell.value = forecast
```

**Output:**

```
[<Cell R2C3 '607.1381980696942'>, <Cell R3C3 '607.1381980696942'>,...,<Cell R32C3 '607.1381980696942'>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want cell 1 to have forecast 1, cell 2 to have forecast 2 and so on. If so then use one loop, rather than two.

Each time your outer loop is executing, it sets the value of every cell in the `forecasting_range` to each value in the `forecasted_session_column`. At the end of each inner loop execution then the cell will only contain the last value.

```py
for i in range(0,len(forecasting_range)):
    forecasting_range[i].value = forecasted_session_column[i]
```

This uses a variable `i` to count keep track of an index in both lists so that they will match up the same. Note that this solution expects both lists to be of the same length.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes sense and the lists have the same length, but I have an error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` at `for i in len(forecasting_range)`. Should I convert the values or is there a different loop method I need to use?

Comment: My bad! I forgot to convert the int to a range, which is basically a list of numbers. See the updated code.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that error, but I believe what is missing is that your solution formats it to a new list and removes the necessary `<Cell R30C4 '*Value*'>` format that is required for me to push this back to a Google Sheet with the `gspread` library. If you look back to my question I set each individual forecast value to the `.value` property of `cell` (`cell.value = forecast`). Any ideas of what to modify? the `forecasting_range[i]?`

Comment: Wow, sorry. Yes, my code originally replaced the entire cell with the value, but now it should set the cell's value as in your example.  I hope. Sorry my answer was so buggy!

Comment: No worries, your detailed answer has been extremely helpful in understanding what was going wrong initially. Looks like a slight error with the `forecasting_range[i].value = forecasted_session_column[i]`, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: Odd. I don't have any experience with gspread so it's difficult to mentally debug. I had assumed that the `forecasting_range` was a list of Cells, but it now seems to be that it may be some other class and that indexing in with the variable `i` is just giving us the value of the cell at index `i`. There is probably a method like `get_cell(i)` you could call instead of the index, or you could probably circumvent this by using the original iterating method combined with a counter:

Comment: `counter = 0
for cell in forecasting_range:
    cell.value = forecasted_session_column[counter]
    counter = counter + 1`

Comment: Darn, that doesn't render the way I wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177363/discussion-between-webman1-and-cphill).

Comment: The above solution works. The latter comments about errors were related to an un-cached Google Sheet pull and not the code above. After a refresh I was able to get it working correctly. Thanks again webMan1!

Answer (score 1):

In your second loop, you're iterating over the list `forecasted_session_column`. You're setting each `cell` to `179`, and then the next value, and then the next, until it's set to `'607.1381980696942'`.

Example from IDLE of what's happening:

```
>>> cells = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for cell in cells:
    for value in values:
        cells[cell] = value
>>> cells
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```